# Как нарисовать цилиндр в OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, mingw, codeblocks

По заданию требуется нарисовать конус, шар и цилиндр, настроить источники света, материалы и т. д.

Загвоздка возникла на рисовании цилиндра. Дело в том, что `gluCylinder`рисует фигуру без оснований, а у Glaux'а с его `auxSolidCylinder` нету версии под MinGW и, соответственно, CodeBlocks.

Как нарисовать обыкновенный цилиндр? Может, есть ещё какие-то библиотеки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рисуете цилиндр с помощью `gluCylinder` и дорисовываете к нему основания с каждой стороны с помощью `gluDisk`.

---

Также можете попробовать изменить *стиль*:

```
GLUquadricObj cylinder;
cylinder = gluNewQuadric();
gluQuadricDrawStyle(cylinder, GLU_FILL);
gluCylinder(cylinder, 10, 0, 10, 20, 20);
```

Comment: @Byulent Это уже отдельный вопрос. Задайте его отдельно, приведите код.